# How can I execute a native SQL script in JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a SQL script with database dump. How can I execute it using Hibernate's `EntityManager`?

I tried it this way:

```
EntityManager manager = getEntityManager(); 
Query q = manager.createNativeQuery(sqlScript);
q.executeUpdate();
```

but it works only when `sqlScript` contains a single SQL query, while I need to run multiple inserts and other complex stuff.

RDBMS:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: what is getEntityManager();???

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Wrap your query with begin end block. Like

```
EntityManager manager = getEntityManager(); 
Query q = manager.createNativeQuery("BEGIN " + sqlScript + " END;");
q.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I'm getting `You have an error in your SQL syntax` with EclipseLink 2.6 and MySQL.

Comment: This answer for Oracle. Omit semicolon and it may work on MySql.

Comment: FYI: Doesn't work for me in Postgres.

Comment: @Jurass can you try with do $$ before begin and $$ after end. https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-use-block-structure-write-anonymous-blocks-and-divide-larger-blocks-logical