# Execute procedure in Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I've got an Orcale DB with one procedure called `Save`. And this is how I run it:

```
 > EXECUTE DBManager.Save;
```

And now I want to do the same using Hibernate.

```
public void save() {
        Session session = null;
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery("EXECUTE DBManager.Save;");
        int updated = query.executeUpdate();

    }
```

This code doesn't work.

```
WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 900, SQLState: 42000
```

What do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I execute a native SQL script in JPA/Hibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358425/how-can-i-execute-a-native-sql-script-in-jpa-hibernate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Oracle you can use code like

```
CallableStatement cs = null;
cs = this.con.prepareCall("{call DBManager.Save}");
ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
```

Comment: What is con? What package is CollableStatement? java.sql?

Comment: `con` is your database connection.  As for `CallableStatement` see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html

Comment: But I'm using a sessionFactory, as you can see. Could you modify your response?

Comment: Also, my query is EXECUTE, but not CALL.

Comment: as per you code `session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` then `session.connection().prepareCall...`

Answer (score 2):

Try like this example

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
    "CALL GetStocks(:stockCode)")
    .addEntity(Stock.class)
    .setParameter("stockCode", "7277");
```