# How to run SQL script using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a requirement to load and run a sql-script (ReportData_pr.sql) which will create some procedures on start-up and run those procedures.

We are using Spring 4.0.2.RELEASE and hibernate 4.3.5.Final for development.

Is it possible to run the script file by using hibernate. If yes how to do that. If not is there any other work around to achieve my goal.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358425/how-can-i-execute-a-native-sql-script-in-jpa-hibernate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I execute a native SQL script in JPA/Hibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358425/how-can-i-execute-a-native-sql-script-in-jpa-hibernate)

Answer (score 1):

You can run your script using nativequery:

e.g.

```
EntityManager manager = getEntityManager(); 
Query q = manager.createNativeQuery("BEGIN"+sqlScript+"END;");
q.executeUpdate();
```

See if that helps

Comment: It might help if you explain what the getEntityManager() method does.