# Running a sql script with sessionfactory

Tags: sql, hibernate

Is there a way to run an external sql script using the SessionFactory ? I know there is a way to specify raw sql but is there a way to run a .sql file ?

Comment: What is the purpose? You could run sql file through hibernate.xml

Comment: I have tried to  do `session.createSQLQuery("BEGIN"+content+ "END").executeUpdate();` but no success but using entity manager you can achieve same thing please visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358425/how-can-i-execute-a-native-sql-script-in-jpa-hibernate

Comment: I wanted to do this a a part of my test suite. I have a testNG suite from which I want to run my application against multiple test data sets. I am using HSQL embeddeddatabase and would have to run a new file in the BeforeSuite.